# Listing(or counting) files in .tar/.tar.gz archives: What is the time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, tar

What is the time complexity for listing file names in a .tar archive?
Is it `O(size(file))` or `O(# of files in archive)`?

According to this Wikipedia article ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing) ), tar archives do not support random access and in order to list the file names "one has to read through the entire archive" and I understand it as `O(size(file))`. From the other hand, each file in tar has a header which specifies the length of the file, so we can just do one hdd seek for each file in there, so in this case time complexity would be just `O(# of files in archive)`.

And what about .tar.gz archives, I suppose in this case we will not be able to perform multiple seeks without uncompressing which would take `O(size(file))` anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your storage!

**uncompressed tar**

For tape archives (you know, "tar"s), linear to byte length, in any case, because fast-forwarding is still linear in time to the length you need to fast-forward.

For small files on modern storage: the same; you don't ask your SSD for 20 Bytes of storage. You get 4kB at once; in theory, this means you could pretty instantly skip over that 1GB file. In practice, my experience tells me that doesn't happen; I honestly don't know why. To me, the "next_block_after" function should just skip forward. *shrugs*

**compressed tar**

yes, in general you'll have to uncompress to know how long the content is to seek somewhere. I don't think there's a compression format that keeps some kind of table with "intermediate" lengths to speed up seeking.

Comment: Zipfiles contain the directory at the end of the archive so it is possible to list the directory in time proportional to the size of the directory. I don't know if that is what your last sentence is about.

Comment: @rici, no it isn't. Compressed tars are not comparable to zip files. the compression is just an outer layer, not aware of the contained file headers.